# SSH via Corkscrew - Where is the config?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

I've read this page: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-use-ssh-via-http-proxy-using-corkscrew-in-ubuntu.html
And it tells me to open up the SSH config file, which was in 2008, located in "~/.ssh/config"
well, it was not a recognized path at all, and the file didn't exist. So, where can i find this file now in 2013 ? I am sure there are made changes, and if anyone know, i would appreciate that

Thanks!
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is still the correct location. You don't have one by default on most systems -- you frequently need to create it and the .ssh directory. See 'man ssh_config' and 'man ssh' for more details.

From man ssh on my system:
     ~/.ssh/
             This directory is the default location for all user-specific con‐
             figuration and authentication information.  There is no general
             requirement to keep the entire contents of this directory secret,
             but the recommended permissions are read/write/execute for the
             user, and not accessible by others.